# Arrangement of this diode

Tags: voltage, current, diodes, protection, zener

I am using this [diode](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#E0000000JelG/a/44000000MCRe/6mQNNp30Q09HKzVDzH8u9fD7MzoxQtWh7KnFpPNz.eI) for a protection of a bidirectional line. I want to protect the line for both positive and negative transient. But struggling to find the connection to make sure the diode helps for bidirectional protection.

Can someone give me a picture on how to do? How to connect between a signal line and ground using this diode?

[image]

Comment: Just disconnect pin 3.

Comment: @TimWilliams, if I disconnect pin 3, how will the current flow during positive and negative transients on the CAN line?

Comment: One of them is forward biased?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use this one: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nup2105l-d.pdf

I'm using this diode for a project in this configuration:

[image]

Don't forget to add a 120 ohm resistor at the end of the line of a CAN transmission.